# Bulk insert of JSON arrays into SQL Server tables column separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

How can I bulk insert JSON arrays into SQL Server 2016 tables with column separated without using JSON file (will get values with outer object from input)

Sample JSON can be found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37292.sql-server-2016-bulk-import-json-file-data-to-table.aspx)

Comment: Have a look at:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37292.sql-server-2016-bulk-import-json-file-data-to-table.aspx

Comment: i cannot import json file(i will get json array in input)

Comment: Have posted an answer! have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Not tested]:

```
[
 { "code" : 001,"name": "Prashant" },
 { "code" : 002,"name": "Steve" }
]
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (code, name)
SELECT code,name
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH (code int, name nvarchar(50))
```

To read from JSON object:

```
{"OUTER":{"ABC":"TEST_WB_New","XYZ":"9085"}} -- Your JSON

INSERT INTO your_table_name
SELECT ABC, XYZ
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
 WITH (
       ABC nvarchar(50) 'strict $.OUTER.ABC',
       XYZ nvarchar(50) '$.OUTER.XYZ' AS JSON
)
```

Comment: can you please tell me with an outer object

Comment: @adams Please post your sample JSON, so I can get an idea!

Comment: {"OUTER":{"ABC":"TEST_WB_New","XYZ":"9085"}}

Comment: same thing i want in bulk.. sample input : {"OUTER":{"ABC":"TEST_WB_New","XYZ":"9085"},{"ABC":"TEST_WB1_New","XYZ":"9086"},{"ABC":"TEST_WB2_New","XYZ":"9087"}}

Comment: @adams JSON is not valid!